# What Permission are needed for a user to access a RemoteApp in Azure Virtual Desktop?

Tags: azure, avd-manager, remoteapp

I have recently setup my first AVD with two application groups, one for a PC and the other for a RemoteApp. I can access both and have configured the RemoteApp group uses to only have access to the application. They can access the workgroup and see the app, authenticate to access it with their AAD details and authenticator app but are then presented with "Sign in Failed. Please check your username and password and try again".

Can you please advise what i am missing and what level of Role Access does the user need to be able to access the app? Do i need to add this as the resource level or the AVD level?

Thanks for the assist.

Chris

Answer (score 1):

According to [MsDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-desktop/azure-ad-joined-session-hosts#assign-user-access-to-host-pools) to resolve `Sign in Failed. Please check your username and password and try again` error . You should assign the **Virtual Machine User Login** or **Virtual Machine Administrator Login** role at either the VMs, resource group, or subscription level.

[image]

I have created a host pool and application group and added the `wordpad` Application to the Application group as shown below.

[image]

To access Application, I added `Virtual Machine User Login` and `Virtual Machine Administrator Login` roles at the subscription level like below:

[image]

Now in Host pool -> RDP properties ->Advanced -> Add `;targetisaadjoined:i:1` and save like below:

[image]

**Note** to access the Application you need to use your virtual machine username and password like [this](https://i.imgur.com/pBIRzws.png)

I am able to sign in with my user account and access the Application successfully like below:

[image]